# How do I search for an entry in tinydb with the the query in json format?

Tags: python, json, tinydb

I have a tinydb with entries of the form:

```
{
    "key0":"value0",
    "key1":"value1",
    "key2":"value2",
    "key3":"value3"
}
```

and I have a function that sends me:

```
{
    search:{
        "key0":"value0",
        "key1":"value1"
    },
    update:{
        "key3":"value3.1"
    }
}
```

the normal search function needs either a `Query()` or a `where('field')` with no direct way of passing multiple search queries than hard concatenating them with & operators.
is there a way where I can search the db for

```
{
    "key0":"value0",
    "key1":"value1"
}
```

and the update the entry with

```
{
    "key3":"value3.1"
}
```